# Android Libgdx writeString, nothing happens

Tags: android, file, libgdx, file-handling, overwrite

This works just fine :

```
FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.internal("data/data.txt");
String dataFile = handle.readString();
```

But when I do this, nothing happens to the file and no error happens either :

```
FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.local("data/data.txt");
handle.writeString( "Hello world", false );
```

I've added this to the manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Does it work on desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to use the permission:
`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`?

It seems that the permission you are trying to use: `WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE` does not exist.
Please check on this list:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. I ended up just using the external storage and then it works fine. I guess that's the way to do it anyways when one wants to save stuff like hiscores etc. in a game.